# Pulse Audio Volume Control Forgets Settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

In `Input Devices` tab port is set to `Line In`, I change it to `Front Microphone`, but it always returns back to `Line In` after restart.

How can I change it permanently?

I guess the reason is that when system boots, mic is not plugged in front, so it switch it to back by default.

- [Removing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94058/cant-volume-or-brightness-levels-be-remembered/110851#110851) the .pulse directory from my home directory didn't work

Some additional info:

`$ pactl list sources` https://gist.github.com/3914307

`$ cat /etc/pulse/default.pa` https://gist.github.com/3914316

`$ arecord -L` https://gist.github.com/3915130

`$ pactl list sources` https://gist.github.com/e6fa252686b4e4529032

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reviewing your pastebins and consulting with the folks in #pulseaudio here is what we will do. Open a terminal and type `pactl list sources` to verify that the Line In is the active port.

```
Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_07.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo

--SNIP--

    Ports:
        analog-input-microphone-front: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, not available)
        analog-input-microphone-rear: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, not available)
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, available)
    Active Port: analog-input-linein
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Once that is verified, we are going to check to make sure we are able to set the port with the pacmd command. `pacmd "set-source-port 1 analog-input-microphone-front"`
Run `pactl list sources` again to verify that the Front Panel is now active.

```
Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_07.0.analog-stereo

--SNIP--

    Ports:
        analog-input-microphone-front: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, not available)
        analog-input-microphone-rear: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, not available)
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, available)
    Active Port: analog-input-microphone-front
    Formats:
        pcm
```

If all was successful we can now put that at the end of your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file as such:

```
set-source-port 1 analog-input-microphone-front
```

As a matter of interest though, you should be aware that PulseAudio is supposed to manage this for you. It should be switching to the Front Panel mic when it is inserted automatically (provided the hardware supports device detection).

Comment: Thanks for detailed instructions. I posted some outputs in my edited question.

Comment: Please also include a pastebin of the output of arecord -L

Comment: Let's see the output of pactl list sources after you select the front panel mic input please.

Comment: I have revised the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick! Regarding last paragraph in your answer, it actually does not. Nothing happens when I plug mic in front panel. It did work on windows though.

Comment: I wonder if your hardware just doesn't support it then. It is supposed to work as expected in 12.04

Comment: If it works under win, I guess it supports. I get a popup in win each time I plug mic in front panel.

Comment: Hmm. It should be working with PulseAudio version 2.0 and above. Also requires a newer linux kernel, but i'm not sure which version. Though the folks in #pulseaudio were a bit unsure about that part as well.

Comment: It's terrible this is needed!

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but let's give it a try.

First, install BUM (Boot-Up Manager). Once installed under System->Administration->BUM simply look for alsa-mixer-save. Tick that so that this service starts during the boot up. Furthermore, feel free to stop any superfluous services to speed up the system.

Restart.

Hopefully now it will save.

Comment: There is no `alsa-mixer-save`, I tried with `alsa-store`, but same thing happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. search in synaptic for "pulse" and "audio" and select packages that it is installed to reinstall and reinstall it.
2. add you go to terminal and

   > sudo adduser username audio
   >
   > sudo adduser username  pulse
   >
   > sudo adduser username  pulse-access
3. adding access for everyone to those folder

/usr/lib/pulse-2.0
/usr/lib/pulseaudio
/etc/pulse
/home/>username>/.pulse